# Is there a shortcut for jumping to the end or the begin from a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate

I know from vim the % to move to associated ( ), { }, [ ]. How can I do that in textmate?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a single command for it, but you can do `Shift-Cmd-B` to select text enclosed by brackets, and then press left or right arrow to get to the beginning or to the end of the block. :/